# Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService: Angular 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I, am new to angular. Trying to resolve this the issue as **can't resolve all parameter for LoginService**

Here is my Login service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginViewModel as loginVM } from "../../viewmodel/app.login.viewmodel"
import { Data as LoginVmData } from '../../viewmodel/app.loginVm'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    private loginUrl = "Account/Authentication";
    private registerUrl = "Account/Registration";

    private _httpClientModule: HttpClient;
    private _loginVmData: LoginVmData;

    constructor(httpClientModule: HttpClient, loginVmData: LoginVmData ) {
        this._httpClientModule = httpClientModule;
        this._loginVmData = loginVmData;
    }


    public LoginHttpCall(): Observable<loginVM> {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this._httpClientModule.post<loginVM>(this.loginUrl, this._loginVmData, { headers });
    }

    public registerHttpCall(_loginVM: LoginVmData): Observable<loginVM> {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this._httpClientModule.post<loginVM>(this.registerUrl, _loginVM, { headers });
    }

}
```

Since I, search in the google and found some hints that it cause due to the circular dependency. I, am not able to figure it out where is the circular dependency in my case.

Here is the login component which calls the login services

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from "../app/app.component";
import { LoginService } from "../../service/account/app.service.account.login";
import { LoginViewModel } from "../../viewmodel/app.login.viewmodel";
import { Data as LoginVmData } from "../../viewmodel/app.loginVm";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
declare var componentHandler: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private _appComponent: AppComponent;
    private _loginService: LoginService;
    private _loginViewModel: LoginViewModel;
    private _loginVmData: LoginVmData;
    private _router: Router;
    constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent, loginService: LoginService, loginViewModel: LoginViewModel, loginVm: LoginVmData, router: Router) {
        this._appComponent = appComponent;
        this._appComponent.menulist = false;
        this._loginService = loginService;
        this._loginViewModel = loginViewModel;
        this._loginVmData = loginVm;
        this._router = router;

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();

    }

    save(modelValue: LoginViewModel, isValid: boolean) {
        if (isValid) {
            this._loginService.LoginHttpCall().subscribe(item => {
                this._loginViewModel.isSuccess = item.isSuccess;
                this._loginViewModel.message = item.message;
                this._loginViewModel.data.userName = item.data.userName;
                this._loginViewModel.data.profilePic = item.data.userName;
                this._loginViewModel.data.isAdmin = item.data.isAdmin;
                if (item.data.isAdmin && item.isSuccess) {
                    this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                } else if (item.isSuccess) {
                    this._router.navigate(['/home'])
                }
            },
                err => {
                    console.log("Error occured.");
                });
        }
    }


}
```

APP.Shared.Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { EqualValidator } from "./components/Validation/equal.validator.directive";
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/usercreation/login.component';
import { MobileComponent } from './components/mobile/mobile.component';
import { SocialComponent } from './components/usercreation/social.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/usercreation/signup.component';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, RegisterComponent, EqualValidator, DashBoardComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MobileComponent,
        SocialComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'mobile', component: MobileComponent },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoardComponent },
            { path: 'signup', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

And the last App.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DashBoardComponent } from "../../components/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import { LoginViewModel } from "../../viewmodel/app.login.viewmodel";
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent {
    public menulist: boolean = true;
    private _dashBoard: DashBoardComponent;
    public _loginVM: LoginViewModel;
    constructor(loginVm: LoginViewModel, dashboard: DashBoardComponent) {
        this.menulist = true;
        this._dashBoard = dashboard;
        this._loginVM = loginVm;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.menulist = true;

    }
}
```

Where is the circular dependency I, am creating I am not able to figure it out.

Please can some help me. I am using Angular 5 with asp.net core 2.0

Comment: Did you import any thing in your app.loginVm.ts file ?

Comment: And why you are injecting component inside another component class ?! could you provide more information of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is related to the `loginVmData: LoginVmData` in the `LoginService`. DI can not detect what is it when trying to inject it. About this you can read [**Dependency Injection in Angular**](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

**But**

Looking at your code, you are just passing this data into the `LoginHttpCall` service. So you can remove it from the constructor and make that method to accept this data, similar to the `registerHttpCall` method. Pass login model in the method instead of injecting it in the constructor.

```
constructor(httpClientModule: HttpClient ) {
   this._httpClientModule = httpClientModule;
}

public LoginHttpCall(loginVmData: LoginVmData): Observable<loginVM> {    
   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');    
   return this._httpClientModule.post<loginVM>(this.loginUrl, loginVmData, { headers });
}
```